# Connecting Access Databases remotely?

Tags: java, ms-access, jdbc

Currently I have a Java application which performs all I wanted and the limitation
 in it is "It only resides on the Local machine for which it needs to work". I have the Access Databases located on a Remote Server and I install the Java app on the remote server to connect the databases using a connection string `jdbc:odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ=D:\\DATA\\DPPI\\DATA\\DPPI\\DPPIPR01.mdb;`

It connects to Access Databases and do all the business logic with them.

#### Enhancements (to be done):

1. Making the application online - not a big issue.
2. Connecting the databases remotely - its the only concern.

If I make the Application Online the Access Databases need to be connecting through network (somewhat like IP or some web address).

#### Problem:

But after going through this [Connect to Access database remotely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11388277/connect-to-access-database-remotely) It seems my requirement can not be completed.

Is there any way if I'm able to upload the database to the online web hosting server and access the database from there only? If yes, then how should I do the connectivity since Access Database connects by giving the fully qualified name containing drive letter and all.

But how should I proceed further so that I may be able to connect the mdb Databases remotely?

#### ADO Solution:

But after going through the link: 
http://webcheatsheet.com/ASP/access_connection_strings.php, it seems we can perform remote Access Database connectivity.

The solution for the ADO is something like:

> connectionString="Provider=MS Remote; Remote Server=http://your_remote_server_ip;" &_ 
>     "Remote Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=c:\your_database_name.mdb"

I'm a tad confused to how Access Database we can connect.

---

There is one more question in my head. 
I'm making use of Type-1 Driver. Should the Type-4 Driver support the remote connectivity?

Comment: Please format properly .Don't use code markups for random sentences.

Comment: where are you memtioning the ip address in the connection , replace it from local host to the ip address of the database system

Comment: Where should I put the Ip Adress is also my concern! Even after doing this connectionString="Provider=MS Remote; Remote Server=http://your_remote_server_ip;" &_ "Remote Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=c:\your_database_name.mdb" and placing the remote Ip. I'm getting the exception stating "No suitable driver found for Provider=MS Remote;..."

Answer (score 3):

If your application is a server side application (like a web application) and your server's OS is Windows then theoretically it is possible to use your Access database. In this scenario, the Access database is local to your application. In your connection string you can simply use the path to the Access database inside your server's file system.

But keep in mind, that Access is a desktop database not made to use it as a server database. This can lead to poor performance and maybe system crashes. And it is possible that there are some licencing issues for this use case.

So even it may be possible to use Access with a server application it is strongly recommended to use a real server database like MySQL, MS SQL Server, etc. Even an embedded database like Apache Derby or H2 would be a better fit.

If your application runs at client side like a fat client, then your only chance to use Access is to put it on a network filesystem, so it is visible from every client. But this works only inside a LAN. If you cannot put it on a network filesystem then you have to use a real server database.

Comment: I will try if I would be able to refer the database from within the Online Server. I have also found HXTT Access(http://www.hxtt.com/access.html), a commercial type 4 driver for MS Access, supports it. But its licensing cost is comparatively high.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `Provider=MS Remote` (RDS) for new development. Here is a quote from the MSDN article

[Microsoft OLE DB Remoting Provider (ADO Service Provider)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms677519%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> Important
>
> Beginning with Windows 8 and Windows Server 2012, RDS server components are no longer included in the Windows operating system (see Windows 8 and Windows Server 2012 Compatibility Cookbook for more detail). RDS client components will be removed in a future version of Windows. Avoid using this feature in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use this feature. Applications that use RDS should migrate to WCF Data Service.

As others have suggested, you should seriously consider using a different back-end database for this particular application.

Answer (score 0):

What if I'm able to call another java application residing on the Server housing the Microsoft Access Databases? Can you please let me know if it can be the solution such that I will have the division of my application into two:
1. The Online java Application performing 2 things: Accepting the requests coming in and waiting for the response to come from another application running on the Server housing the Microsoft Access Databases.
2. The Java application installed on the Server housing the Microsoft Access Databases only responsible for connecting and returning the DTO (Data Transfer Objects) -or some kind of objects in Collections.

So, I would expect a serverside program to handle the communication with the DB and the client application would communicate with the server app.

Please let me know if I should proceed in this manner.

Answer (score 0):

it can be done by marking the traffic and queueing the traffic from the server---to----remote site ---(QOS..quality of service ) .....the two sites will be connected through VPN methods to  reduce the unnecessary hops that will improve the latency plus add the security , thus server and remote site will logically act as if they are on the same network (LAN)

regards ,

Ali Rehan