# update MDB file remotely from other java web server over http

Tags: java, http, ms-access

How to update an MDB file from other machines remotely over the HTTP?
I have 2 machines that are connected by the internet, on the first, I have an MDB file and on the other, I have a java web application, I want to send an SQL query from the java web application to update the MDB file on the other machine over the HTTP.

I tried to use FTP, but it is transferring the whole file b

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Connecting Access Databases remotely?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16771983/connecting-access-databases-remotely)

Answer (score 0):

A file such as word, or power-point or Access?

Well, a horse is a horse is a horse.

A file is a file is a file.

You don't connect to a word file to update it. You don't connect to a Excel file, or a power-point file. And you don't connect to a Access file. You OPEN a file, and THEN modify it. You can't open nor modify files over FTP, nor can you modify them over HTTP either. And you can't even do that with a plane jane text file. These are files - you have to open them to modify them. Or pull a whole copy to one side. Update that file, and then send it back.

So, you don't want to confuse the concept of a simple file, or file based system like say a text file, excel file, or Access file. These are NOT servers or say a service that you connect to. You never open a MySQL file - you connect to a server + service via tc/ip (a socket conneciton) and then send commands back and forth. You NEVER open or touch that MySQL data file. The server updates that file - not you, and not your code.

So, Access is not a server based, or socket connection based service. It is a file based system - not un-like a text file. You don't connect to a text file, you HAVE to open that file - modify it and then save it. You can't do that over http. In fact you can't even do that with FTP either. You can pull the whole file, modify and then send it back to where you got that file from.

Now, you could however setup + create some web service calls or entry points on the one site. You could send that web site some commands, and then code behind on that web site can open up that text file, word file, or in this case the Access file and make changes . But once again, just like MYSQL or say the web server? You not opening the remote file direct - are  you? You are (and can) thus setup some code or web methods (even REST ones) that accept commands, and those (even sql update commands) could then be run by that remote server/service and thus update the file on that target system. In the case of Access data files?

If you look VERY close, even a ODBC connection string ALWAYS ALWAYS resolves to a valid windows path name (and a full legal qualified windows path name at that).

so, while there is a ODBC driver, the software driver still in fact uses a standard windows OS file open command against that plane jane file sitting in the hard disk. So to update that Access file, you need the driver - since it knows how to open that file, and how to update the delicate data file structures inside. So, even via ODBC? Well, it not a socket connection and you not connecting to a server on the other end - but in fact opening a simple windows file. In fact this means that you not only require DIRECT file rights to that access data file - but you actually need the windows file system!

However, sqLite is the SAME thing. There are thus some jdbc drivers. This JDBC concept is VERY similar to ODBC, but is for web based systems. You install a library on one end (where sqlite resides), and then that web service can take your sql commands (updates or query pulls), and thus the web site code now opens that local file, executes sql against it, or does a query pull , and then returns the results of your query - and the web query calls are done via that web service (rest calls) on that server. So, you can in theory shuffle commands between two web servers - and there are some types of "drivers" such as jDBC standards that in theory do wind up giving you a similar experience to ODBC.

Comment: hi , thanks for answering 
the question is how should I do an update on MDB file remotely ?

Comment: You either copy the file local to the machine where you want to make the update. Or you do it how web sites work. You create web service calls to the 2nd site - they can be SOAP calls, but these days everyone uses REST. So you  can pass sql commands and whatever you want to the 2nd web site, and that web site code can then update the rows of data or whatever you want. And you could consider the javascript jdbc driver approach - and once again that would have to setup + installed on that site with the Access mdb or accDB file. You no more connect to a text file then a access file on that site.

Comment: I mean, how can or would you update a text file on that site? Answer: you send commands to that site and the site code is then free to update that file. But you don't connect to a text file, a word file or a Access file. You DO  connect to a database server system like SQL server or MySQL - but then again, you not connecting to a word file, a text file or in this case a Access files. So you just have to keep in mind that you don't and can't connect to a file - you have to OPEN them to modify files sitting on that computer.

Comment: I don't have web server in the machine where the MDB file is exist , this is the issue i just have an exe file there