# how to set access connection string?

Tags: c#, database, ms-access-2010, connection-string

I have 2 PCs - PC1 with program and DB (access) and PC2 with Prog Only.
I want to connect to PC2 to DB in PC1 with a connection string.
Program in PC 1 have this:

```
 OleDbConnection Conn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Nicola\Documents\Buddies_Db\Buddies_Db.accdb;Persist Security Info=False");
```

What do I have to change to apply for PC1 local IP (192.168......)?

Comment: You need to ['share'](http://lifehacker.com/5808814/how-to-share-a-folder-over-your-network-for-beginners) the path to your database and then you can use that share in bot pcs. (Of course the two pcs should be connected to a common network) However, while this scenario is still workable with MS-Access engine, I really recommend you to search for a more -network aware- database engine.

Comment: PCs are connected bot to network , file and folder are shared in PC1. Just i want to know where i have to change the connection string including PC1 ip (local) ?

Comment: related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11388277/connect-to-access-database-remotely

Comment: If you share the folder where the database file is stored on the first pc and give to that folder adequate permissions then you can use the sharename given to that folder to build your connectionstring. IE \\yourFirstPCName\yourShareName\Buddies_Db.accdb and this connection string can be used on both pc in place of the actual path that is valid only on the first PC